# Script returning unexpected error

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file, for-loop

I've got some Code that is written in batch. The script should take a SQLDump of a database, then uses 7zip to zip it up, then archive off the zipped file into a history folder.
Below is my entire script to give context and an idea of what is going on overall but my issue is with the second FOR loop which is this bit here:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%encryptedFile%') DO set encryptedFileSize=%%~zA

    :: Checks the zipped back up is greater than 0 (No failure on zipping)
    IF %encryptedFileSize% GTR %maxbytesize% (
        %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2% %FileName% Encrypted Successfully >> Backup.txt
        ::Move the zip file
        MOVE %FileName%.7z BackupHistory
        ::DEL %FileName% - do i need this?

        ::Deletes error log if the backup is successful; Error log will still be there if backup failed
        DEL %errorLog%
    ) ELSE (
        ::Logs that zip & encryption failed
        @ECHO %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2% %FileName% Encryption Failed 2> ZIPFailure.txt
    )
```

The whole script will run through OK (e.g. Take the dump, zip it) but then when it reaches this next bit which is checking the zipped file is greater than 50KB before moving the file and deleting the original backup it fails. The error it returns on screen is (copy&paste from CMD Prompt is shown just below):

"set encryptedFileSize=50 was unexpected at this time."

Error message received:

```
D:\BackupSchedule\BackupScripts\TestScripts>FOR /F "usebackq" %A IN ('"DailyBack
up.20161230-15-42.7z"') DO set encryptedFileSize=%~zA

D:\BackupSchedule\BackupScripts\TestScripts>set encryptedFileSize=
50 was unexpected at this time.
D:\BackupSchedule\BackupScripts\TestScripts>    IF  GTR 50 (
D:\BackupSchedule\BackupScripts\TestScripts>
```

Full script:

```
   @ECHO onD:
::Set variables for the backup
SET WorkingDirectory=D:\BackupSchedule\BackupScripts\TestScripts
SET BackupFile="DailyBackup.%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%.bak"
SET encryptedFile="DailyBackup.%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%.7z"
SET errorLog="D:\BackupSchedule\BackupScripts\TestScripts\Backup_error_%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%.txt"
SET maxbytesize=50

:: Just writing a line in the error log to break up the days
@ECHO --------------------------------------------------------- >> Backup.txt

cd %WorkingDirectory%

::Create Backup History Folder
IF NOT EXIST %WorkingDirectory%\BackupHistory\ (
      MKDIR %WorkingDirectory%\BackupHistory\
) 

::Take backup
mysqldump.exe --user=S-BackUp --password=SEXOr2 --host=HostIP --port=ChosenPort --result-file=%BackupFile% --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --databases "queue_depth" 2> Backup_error_%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%.txt

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%BackupFile%') DO set size=%%~zA

    :: Checks the Backup isn't 0KB
    IF %size% GTR %maxbytesize% (
        :: Prints the size of backup to the log
        @ECHO %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2% Backup is ^> %maxbytesize% bytes >> Backup.txt
        @ECHO %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2% BackUp %BackupFile% created successfully >> Backup.txt
        ::Zip & Encrypt the backup
        7za.exe a %BackupFile%.7z %BackupFile% -PmyPassword 2>> Backup_error_%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%.txt
    ) ELSE (
        :: Script will stop here if Backup failed
        :: Prints the size of backup to the log
        @ECHO %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2% Backup is ^< %maxbytesize% bytes >> Backup.txt
        @ECHO %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2% BackUp %BackupFile% failed >> Backup.txt
    )

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%encryptedFile%') DO set encryptedFileSize=%%~zA

    :: Checks the zipped back up is greater than 0 (No failure on zipping)
    IF %encryptedFileSize% GTR %maxbytesize% (
        %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2% %FileName% Encrypted Successfully >> Backup.txt
        ::Move the zip file
        MOVE %FileName%.7z BackupHistory
        ::DEL %FileName% - do i need this?

        ::Deletes error log if the backup is successful; Error log will still be there if backup failed
        DEL %errorLog%
    ) ELSE (
        ::Logs that zip & encryption failed
        @ECHO %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2% %FileName% Encryption Failed 2> ZIPFailure.txt
    )
```

Please let me know if you need anymore details around this

Comment: Replace `::`-style comments by `rem`, particularly in parenthesised blocks of code!

Comment: Add `if not exist "%BackupFile%" set "size=0"` between `mysqldump.exe …` and first *FOR* command `FOR %%A IN (%BackupFile%) DO set size=%%~zA` (follow @Mofi's advice) as `%%~zA` results to an empty string if `%BackupFile%` does not exist in the current directory. Apply the same approach for `encryptedFileSize` variable (this means pre-define its value to ensure it's a valid number before comparing as in `IF %encryptedFileSize% GTR %maxbytesize% …`.